# How to use Doctrine DBAL?

Tags: php, doctrine, dbal

I have this folder structure

```
[-] myapp/
    [+] app/
    [-] lib/
        [-] vendor/
            [-] doctrine/
                [-] Doctrine/
                        Common/
                        DBAL/
                        Symfony/
                [+] bin/
    [-] sites/
        [-] default/
            [-] test/
                    test-doctrine-dbal.php
```

And I try the code at documentation

```
    <?php

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php');
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'cdcol',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
);
$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cds";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['titel'];
}
?>
```

And I get warning:

```
Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\myphp\sites\default\test/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php\Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\myphp\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on line 148
```

And an error:

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\myphp\sites\default\test/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php\Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\myphp\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on line 148
```

I don't know much about PHP namespace. Reading about PHP namespace in PHP manual still cannot resolve the problem. Is that code correct if I want to use Doctrine DBAL with that directory structure ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Doctrine library path to the `include_path`. See `get_include_path` and `set_include_path` PHP functions.

Comment: I try add this : set_include_path(realpath(dirname(_ _ FILE _ _).'/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/')); but still return the same error. I put space in _ and _ because double _ not shown up in SO

Comment: @Permana Check whether `realpath` returns string or boolean. You probably have too many/few dots in the relative path or some file permission issues.

Comment: Try to `require` the file manually providing the correct path. Check the file using `is_readable`. Maybe it's a file permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong to me (from the warning)

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\myphp\sites\default\test/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php\Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration.php
```

I don't know that much about php but I don't think that file path can resolve.  For now, try removing **dirname(*_*__FILE_*_*_)** and just hardcoding the path in there.

Comment: I have try without dirname(__FILE__) and still error with same message. I also try adding realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../path') and still error with same message

Comment: when you try hardcoding the path, what is the path that you used?  (ie, save the entire path to a string, echo the string so we can see what it is, and include it using require($myPath);).  If that isn't the issue, are you using a name space?  I ran into some issues with Doctrine when I used my own namespaces  with doctrine.

Comment: the require function is ok. I try to run only the require function and it return no error (I set error_reporting(E_ALL)). I'm not using namespace, but doctrine did.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd parameter of `ClassLoader` constructor is not valid:

> $classLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', **dirname(_*FILE*_).'/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php'**);

The 2nd parameter should be the `include path` of the Doctrine directory and shouldn't be a file.

Therefore, the correct line is:

> $classLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', **'/../../../lib/vendor/doctrine/'**);